# mod-substitute multi-line in apache

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I need to do multiline replacement in httpd.conf. I have tried using mod_substitue and `\n` doesn't seem to work with it.

For example, replace:

`<head>`

with:

```
<head>
<script>
//about 20 lines of scripts
</script>
```

Is there a way to do this in apache 2.4?

Answer (score 1):

> The backslash "\" may be used as the last character on a line to
>   indicate that the directive continues onto the next line. There must
>   be no other characters or white space between the backslash and the
>   end of the line.[*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html#syntax)

```
Substitute "s|<head>|<head>\
Line 1\
Line 2\
...\|ni"
```